# How can I hide old page versions in SXA Search Results in Preview mode?

Tags: experience-editor, content-search, sxa

I created multiple versions for my page. I see only last version in `Search Results` SXA component when page is rendered in normal mode (what is expected).

Although, when I switch to `Preview` mode, all the variants are shown.

How can I filter the data to render only the latest page version in Experince Editor `Preview`?

Reproduced in `Sitecore Experience Accelerator 1.1 rev. 161004 for 8.2`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason you see only the latest version in **normal mode** is the fact that there is only one version in **web** database.

Normally Search Results rendering returns all versions of your item.

This is unexpected behaviour and I would consider this as a bug (by default we should get only the latest version, this is the default Sitecore behaviour).

> **SXA** ticket for that has been created and the issue should be fixed in the next release.

**What you can do for now?**

This probably won't solve your problem because I don't think that there is a way to select distinct items based on some property within Sitecore search query but you can try.

You can filter your searach results with **Search Scope**.

1. Navigate to `tenant/site/settings/scopes`
2. Create new `search scope` item
3. Build Sitecore query to filter you results (in this case I request only items with version number 1)
   [image]
4. Assign your **Search Scope** to **Search Results** rendering
   [image]